# Invariant connection by local diffeomorphism

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let  $\pi:P\to M$ be a principal $G$-bundle on a manifold $M$ endowed with a  connexion $A$. Let $X$ be a  tangent vector field on  $M$  and let  $Y$  be a (not-necessarily horizontal)  lift of $X$ to $P$. In other words, for every $p\in P$ we have
$$\pi_{*,p}(Y_p)=X_{\pi(p)}\ .
$$
The vector field $X$ defines a one-parameter group $(\alpha_t)$ of  local diffeomorphisms of $M$ , and $Y$ defines a one-parameter group $(\beta_t)$ of  local diffeomorphisms of $P$.

Let  $U$ be an open subset of $M$ such that $\alpha_t$ is defined on $U$ and let

$$\alpha_t :U\to V$$

the corresponding diffeomorphism. Then  $\beta_t$ will be  defined over  $\pi^{-1}(U)$ so we obtain a lift

$$\beta_t:\pi^{-1}(U)\to \pi^{-1}(V)$$

of $\alpha_t$.

What is the condition which should satisfy the lift $Y$ of  $X$ such that  every diffeomorphism

$$\beta_t:p^{-1}(U)\to p^{-1}(V)$$

of this type leaves the connection $A$ invariant  (more precisely it maps  the restriction of  $A$ to $\pi^{-1}(U)$ on the   restriction of  $A$ on $\pi^{-1}(V)$).

Comment: I think that your question is a bit confused.  Are you asking for a condition that will produce a lift $Y$ whose flow preserves $A$ for *any* given $X$ on $M$?  When $A$ is not flat, such a lift $Y$ generally will not exist for the general $X$.

Comment: we assume that $X$ is a fixed vector field on $M$ and has a lift $Y$ on $P$,$$\forall p\in P :  \pi_{*,p}(Y_p)=X_{\pi(p)}\ .
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\zeta:\mathfrak g \to \Gamma(VP)$ be the infinitesimal principal right action, where $VP=ker(\pi)$ is the vertical bundle, and describe the connection $A$ equivalently as $\Phi=\zeta\circ\omega:TP\to VP$ where $\omega\in\Omega^1(P,\mathfrak g)$ is the principal connection form. This is the vertical projection associated to $A$. 
The connection is invariant under the flow of your lifted vector field $Y$ iff the Lie derivative of $\Phi$ along $Y$ vanishes: $\mathcal L_Y\Phi =[Y,\Phi] = -[\Phi,Y]=0$. The bracket is the Frölicher-Nijenhuis bracket. See chapters 17 and 19 of [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf) for more details. You could call $-[\Phi,Y]$ the covariant derivative of $Y$ with respect to the connection $A$.

Comment: Peter Michor @ I appreciate of your answer, it was useful.